# Error when using queue in Lua

Tags: list, scripting, lua, queue, local

I am using a queue in Lua
http://www.lua.org/pil/11.4.html

```
List = {}
function List.New ()
    return {first = 0, last = -1}
end

function List.PushRight (list, value)
    local last = list.last + 1
    list.last = last
    list[last] = value
end

function List.PopLeft (list)
    local first = list.first
    if first > list.last then print("error: list is empty") end
    local value = list[first]
    list[first] = nil        -- to allow garbage collection
    list.first = first + 1
    return value
end
```

I access the queue using the following commands:

```
list = List.New

List.PushRight(list, position)

local popped = List.PopLeft(list)

List.PushRight(list, popped)
```

It crashes in the PushRight command on:

```
local last = list.last + 1
```

The error is:

```
attempt to index local 'list' (a function value)
```

'list' is clearly not a function value. It is a List that I instantiated with the key 'last' which I should be able to access with the value -1. Why is it calling list a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is. See `list = List.New`. You meant `list = List.New()`.